# C# generic method based on interface design

Tags: c#, .net, generics, interface, base-class

Have a class as Base:

```
public abstract class DataObjectEntityItemBase
{ }
```

Derived class:

```
public class CatalogDataObjectEntityItem : DataObjectEntityItemBase, ISupportsTabularDataObjectEntityContainer
{ }
```

Have a method:

```
internal void FetchTabSectionDataObjectEntityByParentItem<T1>(
               ITabSectionManager dataObjectEntityContainerOwner, 
               T1 parentDataObjectEntityItem)                                                                                                                             
where T1 : DataObjectEntityItemBase, ISupportsTabularDataObjectEntityContainer
{ }
```

Problem code where I want to call `FetchTabSectionDataObjectEntityByParentItem`:

```
FetchTabSectionDataObjectEntityByParentItem(
       refDoeItem.LinkedConfigurationObject as ITabSectionManager, 
       refDoeItem as ISupportsTabularDataObjectEntityContainer);
```

Error:

> Error CS0311  The type ISupportsTabularDataObjectEntityContainer cannot
>   be used as type parameter 'T1' in the generic type or method
>   FetchTabSectionDataObjectEntityByParentItem(ITabSectionManager,
>   T1)'. There is no implicit reference conversion from
>   ISupportsTabularDataObjectEntityContainer DataObjectEntityItemBase
>   refDoeItem  is variable as DataObjectEntityItemBase type.

`refDoeItem` is variable in type of `DataObjectEntityItemBase`.

Comment: Apart that you are not showing us all the relevant code, I would have thought the error message was pretty obvious?

Comment: @MickyD, as you see I am calling: "FetchTabSectionDataObjectEntityByParentItem(refDoeItem.LinkedConfigurationObject as ITabSectionManager, refDoeItem as ISupportsTabularDataObjectEntityContainer);" Why "refDoeItem as ISupportsTabularDataObjectEntityContainer" is not compatible with constraint "where T1 : DataObjectEntityItemBase, ISupportsTabularDataObjectEntityContainer" ? Thanks.

Comment: What is `refDoeItem`?  I probably would have made `DataObjectEntityItemBase` realise `ISupportsTabularDataObjectEntityContainer`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The constraint is a mechanism during **compile time** which guarantees that the operator or method it has to be called will be supported by any type argument that might be specified by client code.

in your case the constraint `where T1 : DataObjectEntityItemBase, ISupportsTabularDataObjectEntityContainer` means the instance should be derived from `DataObjectEntityItemBase` and implements `ISupportsTabularDataObjectEntityContainer` simultaneously.

by doing the unnecessary casting of *refDoeItem* to `ISupportsTabularDataObjectEntityContainer` you are defying this rule. simply remove the cast and everything should get resolved automatically based on the constraint you defined. but if you need to cast it to another type (e.g. *refDoeItem* is an object) you should cast it to a type which conforms with the whole constraint which in your case is `CatalogDataObjectEntityItem`.